# Resave the DataGridView contect into database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I am saving DataGridView data into SQL database which is running ok. I want to resave the grid but first want to delete the existing rows of same number PO from database. For this i used Delete command of same PO Number before inserting to database.

Now if by any chance there is an error in Insert procedure, it delete the existing rows and shows error.

I want if there is an error, the delete procedure can not be run. how to check this?

```
Private Sub SaveData()
    Try
        DeleteData()

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim answer As Integer
        answer = MsgBox("Are you sure to save?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Save Record")
        If answer = vbYes Then
            ConnecDatabase()
            Sql = "Operation_InsertPO"
            For i = 0 To DGV_PO.RowCount - 1
                    cmd = New SqlCommand
                    With cmd
                        .Connection = Conn
                        .Parameters.Clear()
                        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                        .CommandText = Sql
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@PONo", text_ponumber.Text)
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", DGV_PO.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", DGV_PO.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Units", DGV_PO.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", DGV_PO.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value)
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rate", DGV_PO.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value)
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amt", DGV_PO.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value)
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", GlobalVariables.UserName)
                        .ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End With
            Next
            cmd.Dispose()
            Conn.Close()
            MsgBox("Saved Successfuly", vbInformation)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
    Finally
        If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            Conn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteData()
    Try
        ConnecDatabase()
        Sql = "Operation_DeletePO"
        cmd = New SqlCommand
        With cmd
            .Connection = Conn
            .Parameters.Clear()
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .CommandText = Sql
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@pono", text_ponumber.Text)
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        Conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
    Finally
        If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            Conn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question but I suggest one [avoid AddWithValue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: Run your delete command *after* inserting? Or put it all in the same SP?

Comment: Use a transaction to wrap both the delete and insert operations. The whole point of transactions is to ensure that either all operations complete or none do, i.e. exactly what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Private Sub SaveData()
    Try
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim answer As Integer
        answer = MsgBox("Are you sure to save?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Save Record")
        If answer = vbYes Then
            sql = "SET XACT_ABORT ON " & vbNewLine &
                  "BEGIN Tran Tran_Save " & vbNewLine &
                  "EXEC Operation_DeletePO @pono=" & text_ponumber.Text & vbNewLine
            For i = 0 To DGV_PO.RowCount - 1
                If Not DGV_PO.Rows(i).IsNewRow Then
                    sql += "EXEC Operation_InsertPO" &
                        "  @PONo=" & text_ponumber.Text &
                        ", @ProductCode=" & DGV_PO.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value &
                        ", @ProductName=" & DGV_PO.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value &
                        ", @Units=" & DGV_PO.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value &
                        ", @Qty=" & DGV_PO.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value &
                        ", @Rate=" & DGV_PO.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value &
                        ", @Amt=" & DGV_PO.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value &
                        ", @User=" & GlobalVariables.UserName & vbNewLine 'Environ("Username") 
                End If
            Next
            sql += "COMMIT TRAN Tran_Save"
            ConnecDatabase()
            cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
            MsgBox("Saved Successfuly", vbInformation)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
    Finally
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```